# Get esbuild to watch for changes, rebuild, and restart express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, npm, esbuild

I am trying to create a simple SSR powered project using express + react. To do this, I need to simultaneously watch frontend and backend scripts during development.

The goal here is to use express routes to point to react page components. Now, I have this working, but I am having problems with DX.

Here are my package scripts:

```
    "build:client": "esbuild src/index.js --bundle --outfile=public/bundle.js --loader:.js=jsx",
    "build:server": "esbuild src/server.jsx --bundle --outfile=public/server.js --platform=node",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "start": "node ./public/server.js"
```

Now this works if I do `npm run build && npm run start`, but the problem is that it doesn't watch for changes and rebuild the frontend bundle or restart the backend server.

Now, if I add `--watch` to the 2 build scripts, it only starts watching the `index.js` file and does not execute the other scripts.

So if I add `nodemon` to my start script, it doesn't matter because esbuild won't get past the first script due to the watcher.

Is there a simpler way of doing what I am trying to do here? I also want to add tailwind to this project once I figure this out, so any tips around that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hello did u manage to figure it out I'm having the same issue and actually the same structure as u. How did u add the server and client builds in the JavaScript version of building + watching for changes ?

Comment: @Frozendawn i ended up using a package called `concurrently` to run the scripts in parallel. you can also use `npm-run-all` package with the `--parallel` flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the JS interface to esbuild, i.e., write a small JS script that requires esbuild and runs it, and then use the functional version of https://esbuild.github.io/api/#watch. Something like this:

```js
require('esbuild').build({
  entryPoints: ['app.js'],
  outfile: 'out.js',
  bundle: true,
  watch: {
    onRebuild(error, result) {
      if (error) console.error('watch build failed:', error)
      else { 
        console.log('watch build succeeded:', result)
        // HERE: somehow restart the server from here, e.g., by sending a signal that you trap and react to inside the server.
      }
    },
  },
}).then(result => {
  console.log('watching...')
})
```

---

#### Update

To get the same behavior in esbuild 0.17+:

```
const config = {
  // entryPoints:
  // ...
  plugins: [{
    name: 'rebuild-notify',
    setup(build) {
      build.onEnd(result => {
        console.log(`build ended with ${result.errors.length} errors`);
        // HERE: somehow restart the server from here, e.g., by sending a signal that you trap and react to inside the server.
      })
    },
  }],
};

const run = async () => {
  const ctx = await esbuild.context(config);
  await ctx.watch();
};

run();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this API seems to have changed.

Comment: It looks like it was deprecated in version 0.17 and later and you now use context as in @Zahin's solution above.

Answer (score 19):

I use this code snippet to watch my custom react and esbuild project

```js
const esbuild = require("esbuild");
async function watch() {
  let ctx = await esbuild.context({
    entryPoints: ["./src/app.tsx"],
    minify: false,
    outfile: "./build/bundle.js",
    bundle: true,
    loader: { ".ts": "ts" },
  });
  await ctx.watch();
  console.log('Watching...');
}
watch();
```

For more details: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#watch

Comment: Excellent ! Note that one can set `logLevel` in BuildOptions to eg `info` to be told when a rebuild succeeds after an error occured.

Comment: It's working like a charm. But I think this is only proper for dev environment, if you want to run build for production, you may need another script file without watch.

Comment: Not necessary. You can create and pass extra flag support like "--dev" or "--prod" with your script.

Answer (score 6):

`@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-serve` or `@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-start` are two esbuild plugins that can run your bundles or any command line script (similarly to nodemon) for you after building your project (supports watch mode for rebuilding and rerunning on file changes).

Doing this is as easy as:

```
import serve from '@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-serve';

/** @type import('@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-serve').ESServeOptions */
const options = {
  ... // Any options you want to provide.
};

export default {
    ..., // Other esbuild config options.
    plugins: [serve(options)],
};
```

The documentation can be found at the following:

- [@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-serve)
- [@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-start](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@es-exec/esbuild-plugin-start)

Disclaimer: I am the author of these packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and solved it with [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)

In my case I was building a VS Code extension, so my package.json script line looks like this:

```
  "esbuild-watch": "npm-run-all --parallel esbuild-base esbuild-server -- --sourcemap --watch",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESModules you can use this code:

```js
import { context } from 'esbuild';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const entryPoints = ['source1', 'source2', 'source3', 'source4']
  .map(name => `./folder/js/${name}.js`);

(async function(){
  try {
    let ctx = await context({
      entryPoints,
      bundle: true,
      outdir: resolve('public/js'),
    });

    await ctx.watch();
    
    console.log("ESBuild Watching...");
  } catch (error) {
    process.exit(1)
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP asked, but if you need to bundle in dev and if you happen to use pnpm and node >= v18.11.0, you don’t need any extra packages because pnpm can run scripts parallel [with a simple regex pattern](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#running-multiple-scripts), and node has a [`--watch` flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--watch) to restart the server on changes:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pnpm run /^dev:.*/",
    "dev:watch": "node ./scripts/buildWatch.mjs",
    "dev:start": "node --watch-path=./src ./build/server.js",
  }
}
```

I needed to build the server and worker in separate files so my esbuild ended up looking like this:

```js
// buildWatch.mjs
import esbuild from 'esbuild'

/** @type {import('esbuild').BuildOptions} */
const opts = {
  bundle: true,
  format: 'esm',
  logLevel: 'info',
  packages: 'external',
  platform: 'node',
  sourcemap: false,
  target: ['node20'],
}

/** @type {import('esbuild').BuildOptions} */
export const serverBuildOpts = {
  ...opts,
  entryPoints: ['./src/server.ts'],
  outfile: './build/server.js',
}

/** @type {import('esbuild').BuildOptions} */
export const workerBuildOpts = {
  ...opts,
  entryPoints: ['./src/worker.ts'],
  outfile: './build/worker.js',
}

async function watch() {
  const serverCtx = await esbuild.context(serverBuildOpts)
  const workerCtx = await esbuild.context(workerBuildOpts)

  await Promise.all([serverCtx.watch(), workerCtx.watch()])
}

watch()
```

Build script follows the same pattern:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pnpm run /^build:.*/",
    "build:server": "node ./scripts/buildServer.mjs",
    "build:worker": "node ./scripts/buildWorker.mjs",
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what oder `pnpm run /^dev:.*/` runs the scripts, since I need the build to run before the server restarts, but so far it has worked.

Pretty neat. Thanks to all the answers in this thread.